# array in procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Создаю процедуру типа:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE func
    @tmp  INTEGER,
    @lot INTEGER,
    @qty  INTEGER
AS
```

Чтобы передавать туда что-то вроде:

```
EXEC func
    @tmp = 77,
    @lot = 191,
    @qty = 102;
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы можно было передать множество значений произвольной длинный (типа массив)? Например:

```
EXEC func
    @tmp = 77,
    @lot = 191, 201, 199, 63,
    @qty = 102, 314, 271;
```

Answer (score 3):

Если версия сервера 2008 и старше, то можно использовать [Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx):

```
CREATE TYPE intTable AS TABLE (value int)
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE func
    @tmp intTable READONLY,
    @lot intTable READONLY,
    @qty intTable READONLY
AS 
BEGIN
   ...
END;
GO
DECLARE @t intTable, @l intTable, @q intTable;
INSERT @t (value) VALUES (77);
INSERT @l (value) VALUES (191), (201), (199), (63);
INSERT @q (value) VALUES (102), (341), (271);

EXEC func @tmp = @t, @lot = @l, @qty = @q
```

Comment: не, ну вы что...эти числовые данные не статичные, они для примера...они могут быть такими какими их напишет кто-нибудь...любые, разные..суть вопроса такая, как к примеру не обязательно числа, а к примеру строку разить

Comment: то есть:
EXEC func
    tmp = 77,
    lot = 1-100;2-200;3-300;
и на выходе была таблица:

1......100
2......200
3......300